# Get all records using join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables like the following:

**Table1**

```
Id Table1_Col 
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
```

**Table2**

```
 Id Table1_Col Table2_Col
 1    A           Test
```

I want the count of (Table1_Col) in **Table2**  and I need query for the following output:

**Expected Output**

```
Table1_Col     Count_Table2_Col
    A                 1
    B                 0
    C                 0
    D                 0
    E                 0
```

What I have tried so far:

```
select Table1_Col,Count(Table2_Col) from table1 t1
Left outer join table2 t2 on t1.Table1_Col = t2.Table1_Col
```

Please provide me a proper solution for this.

Comment: That is the proper solution, you just need to add a group by.

Comment: still same output

Comment: You are just missing the `GROUP BY` clause. It looks good otherwise!

Comment: plz check my scnario in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=618162905b00d6ecb1acb77e1c2f7b1a

Comment: @Rajasekar As per the revised fiddle, please check my [revised answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56427916/2451726)

Answer (score 3):

You need `GROUP BY`, when using aggregate methods. Also `Table1_Col` existing in both tables, so please use with the proper table alias for the columns.

The query below will return your expected result. Please find the demo too.

```
select T1.Table1_Col, Count(T2.Table2_Col) AS Table2_Col
from table1 t1
Left outer join table2 t2 on t1.Table1_Col = t2.Table1_Col
GROUP BY T1.Table1_Col
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fe7f47e0f8691f3aae94c34b1ac583fd)

---

**UPDATE:** As per [the comment in the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56427801/get-all-records-using-join/56427916#comment99450943_56427801), based on your fiddle, the condition `t3.visitno=1` should be in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and not in the `WHERE` clause, so the following query will work:

```
select t3.pvisitno, t1.DocName, count(t2.vdocid) as [count]
from Document_type t1
left outer join visitdocs t2 on t2.DocId = t1.DocId
left outer join visittbl t3 on t3.visitno = t2.visitno and t3.visitno=1
group by t3.pvisitno,t1.DocName
order by count(t2.vdocid) desc
```

[**db<>fiddle demo for the revised fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=54e4d20ed96f910410ead5b8d638dc29)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
select t1.Table1_Col,
       sum(case when Table2_Col is null then 0 else 1 end) Count_Table2_Col
from Table1_Col t1
left join Table2 t2 on t1.Table1_Col = t2.Table1_Col
group by t1.Table1_Col
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Declare @t table ( id int ,col varchar(50))

insert into @t values (1,'A')
insert into @t values (2,'B')
insert into @t values (3,'C')

Declare @t1 table ( id int ,col varchar(50),col2 varchar(50))

insert into @t1 values (1,'A','TEST')

select t.col,count(t1.id) countT2 from @t t left join @t1 t1
on t.id=t1.id
group by t.col
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
select t1.Table1_Col, coalesce(x.cnt, 0) cnt
  from table1 t1 
  left outer join (select Table2_Col, count(*) cnt from table2 group by Table2_Col) x 
    on x.Table2_Col = t1.Table1_Col;
```

The idea here is to create an inline view of table2 with its counts and then left join that with the original table.

The "coalesce" is necessary because the inline view will only have records for the rows in table2, so any gaps would be "null" in the query, while you specified you want "0".